# completely remove a check-in

Tags: version-control, tfs

I'm not looking for rollback - I know how that works.

Does TFS support complete destruction of a check-in? Say I accidentally check my entire MP3 library into the repository (ala [Eric Sink's example](http://www.ericsink.com/vcbe/html/dvcs_weakness_obliterate.html)) - I know I can delete these from the repository, or if I make a change, I can roll it back (restore a previous version), but can I actually remove evidence of the check-in altogether?

I know I shouldn't want to do this - I'm not interested in reasons why it's a bad idea - but just if TFS supports it.

Comment: I would be surprised if this were possible. It would be a security issue.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Using the tf destroy command is pretty destructive: http://manyrootsofallevilrants.blogspot.nl/2012/11/delete-changesetfile-in-tfs-2010-using.html

Comment: just to clarify, you can't delete changeset, only files or folders

Comment: @AntonioBakula Thanks for the clarification - that's what I was wondering about!